# Set Aspect Ration of Img in ul

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to set the aspect ratio of this image within a `ul`. It is currently displaying much too large in terms of height than I want. I have tried many things including surrounding it with another `div` and adding `padding-top: 56.25%;` to the div, but nothing is working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<div class="col-md">
   <ul class="one">
       <a href="{% url 'link' %}">
       <li class="two">
           <img class="three" src="{% static 'home/img.jpg' %}">
           <div class="title">
               <div class="title__tag">
                   <p class='text'>Book Your Free Consultation Now</p>
               </div>
           </div>
        </li>
        </a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
.one{
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: auto;
}

.two {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.three {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  float: left;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is your expected behavior ?

Comment: The image is displaying as a square, I'd like to force an aspect ratio of around 16:9

Comment: Please update your post with expected and actual screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing to note first, you should move your `<a>` into the `<li>`. Valid HTML dictates that only `<li>` elements should directly follow a `<ul>`.

There are a few different ways you could accomplish what you're describing. One quick and simple way would be to take advantage of how easy to use the `background` CSS properties are, like in this codepen:
https://codepen.io/barneychampaign/pen/mdEvMPd

See if that creates the effect you're looking for.